# How to put all the information into one sentence?

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number

> we have conducted half-month fieldwork twice in 2018 and 2019,
>   respectively.
>
> we have conducted two times of half-month fieldwork in 2018 and
>   2019, respectively.

I want to descript our fieldwork conducted in 2018 and 2019. A total of two times; each time the fieldwork lasted half a month. How to put all the information into one sentence.

Comment: Why is "one sentence" important to you?  Usually well written English expresses one main idea in a sentence.  Would it not be better to write two clear sentences instead of one unclear sentence.

Comment: I need this written concisely because I am trying to build my cv. So space is limited.

Comment: Two short sentences are often shorter than one longer one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there are two ideas here: *two trials* and *half a month* these should be expressed in separate sentences.  If you think these are closely linked you can join the sentences with a conjunction or a semicolon.

> We conducted fieldwork trials in 2018 and 2019; both trials lasted half a month.

It might be better to say "two weeks" instead of "half a month". It is implicit that there were two trials. You could make this explicit, but that would be a third major idea and should have its own sentence. I've used past tense, since a past time "2018 and 2019" is specified.